# load local html/template file in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to write a local mobile application using `jquery` mobile without a server. i want to split the views into separated html/template file. so i need to load them during running, I use the following way like :

```
$.get('views/somepage.tmpl')
```

on Firefox, it works, but on chrome, there is a cross-domain problem, the error information is:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

so what i want to ask is that:
any solution for it, i don't want to write all Htmls into one file.

thanks in advances

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6075747/474535) for more info and a possible (insecure) solution

Answer (score 0):

Despite of some standards, there are some differences between web browsers. Try to change your file's path to full directory. For example:

```
"D:/index.html"
```

And if this won't work try to add "file:///". For example (I think, this one won't work with firefox;) ):

```
file:///D:/index.html
```