# Iframe Errors Ahoy

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The following iframe is designed to fit to it's content. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

```
<iframe src="Splash.html" seamless=true width=99% height=100% scrolling=no name="Content" id="Content" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 10;">
</iframe>
```

When the page is loaded in Chrome, I get the following errors:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. Index.html:35
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

Why would it think that the iframe is undefined when I specifically used the onload event? I'm rather new to web design; forgive me if the problem is obvious.

Comment: Have you tried add "" each attribute?

Comment: Could you rephrase that? I don't understand what you're trying to say, sorry.

Comment: The error is saying you have a cross domain error. You working on file protocol?

Comment: It's all in the same folder, on the same machine written from scratch.

Comment: @Someone Don't you know what attribute is? i.e (for example) seamless=true, have you tried make it this way: seamless="true".

Comment: @Yotam, Now I get what you're trying to say. I'll try it; thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Url Cross Domain Issue in Chrome- Unexpected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060786/file-url-cross-domain-issue-in-chrome-unexpected)

Comment: @Someone: You are running afoul of a limitation in Chrome's security policies that restricts what you are able to do when it really should not.

Comment: No effect. I placed double quotes around all attributes. I've found that the seamless attribute never works anywho. That's why I had to write up this bogus kludge.

Comment: @Jon, How would I disable this feature? I'm running on a Windows 7 laptop.

Comment: @Someone: Follow the links from the answer I linked to. But it would also be a good idea to think about what you are trying to do here, as the method of choice looks very dubious to me.

Comment: Spend the 5 minutes and set up a server on the machine.

Comment: I have to upload the files to an online school, so tinkering isn't much of an option. I'll just notify my teacher. Thanks for the answers! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try it without the true thingy:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_iframe_seamless

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should include the essential parts of the answer in your post and add the link as a reference. Links don't live forever so these kinds of answers can become invalid.