# Load a KML file using geoXml3 parser from a local drive and not localhost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a need where I am loading a kml file using geoXml3 parser.Initially I  was using this synatx given below beacause my file was taken feom localhost and worked all fine.

```
geoXml1 = new geoXML3.parser({map: map,infoWindow: infowindow,singleInfoWindow: true,zoom: myGeoXml3Zoom, markerOptions: {optimized: false},createMarker: createMarker});
geoXml1.parse('central1.kml');
```

But now I have a need where the user uploads a KML file and it gets stored at a particular location for eg.D:/kmlUpload/stations.kml

Now I need to parse the file from this location.How should I do.I am new to this method.Please guide.

Comment: Loading files using XmlHttpRequest is browser specific, it will work in some browsers, not in others.  You may be able to configure the browser to allow it (again depending on the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060786/file-url-cross-domain-issue-in-chrome-unexpected